# How can i add my custom cordova plugin in my android App?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a native android sdk which uses phone camera. I want to add a custom cordova plugin so that i can use that android code for web as well using plugins(google suggested it can be done). can someone please suggest me how it can be done?

I am able to create plugin but not able to add it to android code.
And from googling it is suggested that for that i need to create a cordova project first. I made a cordova project for testing purpose added platforms as-android, ios.
But I'm unable to get even the layout of that project so that i can even edit.

I have my native android code, please suggest me how can i add a cordova in native android project.

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code you have written so far?

Comment: thanks @deHaar, i got to resolve the issue on my own.